Cannot invoke "io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.get$ref()" because "schema" is null
I am trying to load swagger API for b2bpunchout API but it is failing with the following error and throwing 400 error 

ERROR [hybrisHTTP29] [AbstractRestHandlerExceptionResolver]
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.get$ref()" because "schema" is
null      at
de.hybris.platform.swaggerintegration.config.CommerceTypeNameProvider.doReplace(CommerceTypeNameProvider.java:117)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at
java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
at
java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at
java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
at
de.hybris.platform.swaggerintegration.config.CommerceTypeNameProvider.replaceSchemas(CommerceTypeNameProvider.java:109)
at
de.hybris.platform.swaggerintegration.config.CommerceTypeNameProvider.removeSuffixFromParameters(CommerceTypeNameProvider.java:89)
at
de.hybris.platform.swaggerintegration.config.CommerceTypeNameProvider.customise(CommerceTypeNameProvider.java:50)
at
org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.lambda$getOpenApi$7(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:349)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.lambda$getOpenApi$8(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:349)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)    at
org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.getOpenApi(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:349)
at
org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.openapiJson(OpenApiResource.java:134)
at
org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiWebMvcResource.openapiJson(OpenApiWebMvcResource.java:113)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)   at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:903)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:809)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)     at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:338)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:426)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
com.avantor.occ.v2.filters.AvantorIsMigratedFlagFilter.doFilterInternal(AvantorIsMigratedFlagFilter.java:36)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.b2bpunchoutocc.filter.PunchOutRequestMatchingFilter.doFilterInternal(PunchOutRequestMatchingFilter.java:62)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.messagecentercsocc.filters.Oauth2UserFilter.doFilter(Oauth2UserFilter.java:49)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.auth.GuestRoleFilter.doFilterInternal(GuestRoleFilter.java:61)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.v2.filter.CartMatchingFilter.doFilterInternal(CartMatchingFilter.java:38)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.personalizationservices.filter.CxOccPersonalizationFilter.doFilterInternal(CxOccPersonalizationFilter.java:42)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
com.hybris.yprofile.consent.filters.OCCConsentLayerFilter.doFilterInternal(OCCConsentLayerFilter.java:55)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.cmsocc.filter.CMSPreviewTicketFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSPreviewTicketFilter.java:81)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.filter.SessionCurrencyFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionCurrencyFilter.java:36)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.filter.SessionLanguageFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionLanguageFilter.java:39)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.filter.Europe1AttributesFilter.doFilterInternal(Europe1AttributesFilter.java:36)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.filter.ConsentFilter.doFilterInternal(ConsentFilter.java:60)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.v2.filter.UserMatchingFilter.doFilterInternal(UserMatchingFilter.java:93)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:218)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:190)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.multicountry.filter.MulticountrySessionAttributesFilter.doFilterInternal(MulticountrySessionAttributesFilter.java:99)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.v2.filter.BaseSiteMatchingFilter.doFilterInternal(BaseSiteMatchingFilter.java:58)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.multicountry.filter.IdentifyCmsUserFilter.doFilterInternal(IdentifyCmsUserFilter.java:26)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:161)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.PolyglotPersistenceCallbackFilter.doFilter(PolyglotPersistenceCallbackFilter.java:36)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.RestSessionFilter.doFilter(RestSessionFilter.java:39)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:37)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:35)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:308)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:216)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:193)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:113)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.SessionHidingFilter.doFilter(SessionHidingFilter.java:34)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:106)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:351)
at
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:299)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


remove that reference

After adding null check for schema object it got resolved and able to see the API details in swagger. It is a OOTB file needs to be modified.
